# Bash Script that gets a count of running processes and then emails if over a certain threshold

Tags: bash, rhel

I am trying to create a script to grab the current number of running processes and the if that number is over 1000 then send me an email. I am trying to do this in a bash script that I will just use a cron job to call it. The code I am using is below and I am sure I just have something out of place and just need another set of eyes.

```
PCOUNT=$(cat /proc/loadavg|awk '{print $4}'|awk -F/ '{print $2}')
if [$PCOUNT > 100]; then
    mail -s "Process Count" email@example.com
fi
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: "Your question must contain code that is already working correctly"

Comment: `awk` is able to take an input file as an argument, therefore you can remove this [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat). Moreover, use `if (( pcount > 100 )); then ...;fi` instead, and read *Conditional Blocks* in [TestAndConditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of trial and error I finally found a solution. I ended up taking the output of the awk statement and writing it to a file. I then cat the file and send the output to mail.

```
PCOUNT=$(awk -F" |/" '{print $5}' /proc/loadavg)
if ((PCOUNT>1000)); then
    echo "Number of Running Processes is" $PCOUNT >>/tmp/mail.txt
    cat /tmp/mail.txt | mail -s "Number of processes is rising" example@email.com
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context is incorrect on your `if` statement.  Try `(( ))` instead of `[]` on your `if` like shown below:

```
PCOUNT=$(cat /proc/loadavg|awk '{print $4}'|awk -F/ '{print $2}')
if (( $PCOUNT > 100 )); then
    mail -s "Process Count" email@example.com
fi
```

NOTE:  I don't have `mail` setup on my system so I could not verify the `mail` command.

Answer (score 0):

- you can cut down awk to

  awk  -F" |/" '{print $5}' /proc/loadavg
- if condition

  [ $PCOUNT -ge 1000
- mail, pass the $PCOUNT

  mail -s "Process Count: $PCOUNT"

IMHO, if this is for alert why dont you try nagios plugin